# Method chaining and the finishing problem

Tags: dsl, fluent, method-chaining

are there any approaches, given a statement like the following

```
First().Second();
```

to know from within `First()` whether/when `Second()` has executed?

Reference: http://martinfowler.com/dslwip/MethodChaining.html

Answer (score 2):

`Second()` will not execute until `First()` has completed, therefore this is impossible. All that `First()` can do is to violate fluency, thereby making it impossible for `Second()` to run.

Comment: I wouldn't say impossible, though. I was wondering if playing with CallContext or threads there would be a clean way to achieve it.