# Ensuring that a call is made to end a chain of methods

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-interface

Note/Disclaimer: After a few searches, the nearest thing I have I have seen to this post is a post on SO ([Method chaining and the finishing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146623/method-chaining-and-the-finishing-problem)) which is similar to my question, but doesn't really answer it - but anyway, I hope this is not a duplicate question.

**What I am doing:**

I have created a fluent interfaceas a facade over an existing logging framework for a bunch of method calls - so my syntax looks a bit like this:

```
Logger.Debug().Message("Debug message!").WriteToLog();
Logger.Error().Message("An exception occured").Exception(ex).WriteToLog();
```

I am passing an internal object from one method call to the next object so that when the final call is made (the WriteToLog method); the message is written to a log file somewhere.

**The bit I think smells**

In order to verify (only when the application is built in debug mode), I have a property on a context class (just a property bag object) which gets passed from method call to the returned object until the chain terminates; it is a boolean and defaults to false.

This property is evaluated in the context class destructor using a Debug.Assert to determine if the final method to end the chain is called so any logging errors can be picked up during development.
(the property, the code which sets the property and the destructor itself are all created in the context of a #if DEBUG pre-processor directive, so if it is built in release or if the symbol doesn't exist, the code will not get compiled.)

I *know* using a destructor is bad in c#2.0 and above, and that I may not have access to properties because I believe there are no guarantees about the finalization order. This is why it only happens when built in Debug mode, and why I would like to get away from it.

The reason I am trying to build an assertation in is because it is very easy to forget and end up writing code like

```
Logger.Debug().Message("Debug message!");
```

which means that nothing gets logged, though at a cursory glance it looks like it should.

**My Question**

What I want to know is - can anyone think of another way of verifying that the final method is always called? These messages are just required during development to highlight to the developer that a method chain hasn't finished - I don't want the end users finding error messages related to logging in the end product.

Comment: +1 for an elegantly-presented/formatted question.

Comment: Why have the fluent API at all? what's wrong with simply `Logger.Debug("Debug message!");` and `Logger.Error("An exception occurred", ex);`? Seems to me that you're making your logging API more complicated than it needs to be... Fluent APIs are a nice concept but they are no silver bullet, don't try and use them everywhere just because you can.

Comment: @TrevorPilley Because That is similar to what I have got at the moment and it is causing more problems than this does. There are overloads for formatting strings, accepting exception details or both which leads devs to forget to pass in a string format argument, or exception detail which ends up generating an error. The last thing I want is a diagnostic tool throwing an error, which is why I want a fluent interface so I can be explicit about what gets passed in where. It is not something I can swap out, but hopefully can put a facade over.

Comment: @Jay the clue there is "it is causing more problems than this" I would suggest throwing it away and just using log4net or NLog and concentrating on actually adding value to the product instead of wasting time with this fluent API for something that doesn't need it.

Comment: @TrevorPilley Sorry, that doesn't help. Swapping out the logging isn't an option because of the amount of work it would take.

Comment: How many variations of `WriteToLog` are there? Could `Message` become the final part of the fluent syntax? Typically people don't forget a message.

Comment: `Install-Package NLog`, find and replace & you'll be done in half a morning :)

Comment: @TrevorPilley - I have a similar project and  while I can't speak for OP there is value to an inline syntax that allows you to add ancillary data. For example a log that lets you attach object graphs, queries, etc ends up being a lot less  clumsy in fluent syntax than with overloads, args, etc. I'd agree that not everything needs to be fluent but I think there is value to it here.

Comment: @KellyGendron In that case, you probably want to use [Serilog](http://serilog.net/) instead

Comment: @TrevorPilley - Will take a look, thanks. Then again sometimes I really enjoy reinventing the wheel, gives me something to do on the weekend :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all I would question the need for a fluent interface in this case at all, seems you can easily get by with a much simpler interface:

```
Logger.Debug.Message("Test");
```

or even just:

```
Logger.Debug("Test");
```

However, if you really need/want a fluent interface, a different way to do this would be to make the fluent interface work on a parameter to the method, instead of upon the return value.

So instead of doing this:

```
Method1().Method2().Method3();
```

and then forgetting the final call:

```
Method1().Method2().Method3().Execute();
```

you would instead organize the code, perhaps like this:

```
Method1(o => o.Method2().Method3());
```

To do this, you would define an object upon which you will call all the fluent methods:

```
public class LoggerOptions
{
    public LoggerOptions Debug() { LoggerType = LoggerType.Debug; return this; }
    public LoggerOptions Error() { LoggerType = LoggerType.Error; return this; }
    public LoggerOptions Message(string message) { ...; return this; }

    public LoggerType Type { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Every method call here would modify the LoggerOptions object, and then return the same instance back, to continue the fluent interface.

and then:

```
public static class Logger
{
    public static void Log(Func<LoggerOptions, LoggerOptions> options)
    {
        LoggerOptions opts = options(new LoggerOptions());
        // do the logging, using properties/values from opts to guide you
    }
}
```

You would then call it like this:

```
Logger.Log(opts => opts.Debug().Message("Debug message"));
```

If you have some terminal methods you absolutely need to call before finalizing setting up the options object, you can make different objects:

```
public class LoggerOptions
{
    public LoggerOptions Debug() { LoggerType = LoggerType.Debug; return this; }
    public LoggerOptions Error() { LoggerType = LoggerType.Error; return this; }
    public LoggerOptions Message(string message) { ...; return this; }

    public LoggerType Type { get; set; }
    ...

    public LoggerFinalOptions ToEventLog() { ...; return new LoggerFinalOptions(this); }
    public LoggerFinalOptions ToFile(string fileName) { ...; return new LoggerFinalOptions(this); }
}
```

and then:

```
public static class Logger
{
    public static void Log(Func<LoggerOptions, LoggerFinalOptions> options)
    {
        LoggerFinalOptions opts = options(new LoggerOptions());
        // do the logging, using properties/values from opts to guide you
    }
}
```

This would then guarantee that you could not compile the code without ending the chain of methods with a call to something that returns the explicit final options object:

```
// will not compile
Logger.Log(opts => opts.Debug().Message("Test"));

// will compile
Logger.Log(opts => opts.Debug().Message("Test").ToFile("log.log"));
```

Comment: Great answer, just tested and this is exactly what I was looking for. With the slight modification of making the method signature Log(Expression<Func<Option>> expr) I am able to get a verifiable fluent interface which only gets compiled (so it only does stuff like string formatting) if the logging mode is enabled. Thanks!